# Punctuation Structure

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, punctuation, abbreviations, em-dash

**And don't let anyone play tricks with you. I - er - gather that discipline was not always your strong point at Melbury?**

This text is from Good Bye Mr. Chips (Novel, first chapter). Can anyone explain the use of punctuation and interruption **I - er - gather** including the question mark in the end of the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speaker is hinting delicately that the person he is addressing (Mr. Chips?) had a reputation at Melbury (his previous school?) for not being able to keep his class in order. *I gather* means *I believe, I have heard*, and the hesitation (*er*) adds to the tentative nature of the statement, as does the question mark - *it's true, isn't it?*